# an angel of a girl ([an angel of / a girl] or [an angel / of a girl]) or [an angel / of / a girl]

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

> an angel of a girl

You know, the phrase above means a girl is like an angel: angel-like

So I wonder if 'an angel of', especially 'of', includes the meaning of 'like'.

Q1. If it's not, which word or a group of words includes the meaning of 'like'?

There are also similar expressions: a lion of a man, a mountain of a wave, etc.

Q2. Can we use the structure (a noun(A) of a noun(B) to make an (A)-like B phrase without any specific restrictions or can we use only idiomatic expressions already firmed and accepted?

Q3. Are the following phrases idiomatic: a paint of a house(nice house), a stone of a head(low IQ), a snake/fox of a woman(cunning), a puppy of a boy(cute, lovely), an ice of a teacher(strict),  a parasite of a man(idle)

Comment: It has the sense of 'a girl with the qualities of an angel'. Your examples are not idiomatic and not all of them make sense. You can call a person a parasite without needing to add 'of a man'. A female fox is a vixen; you could say _a vixen of a woman_.

Comment: Which part makes 'like'?

Comment: @KateBunting I once said to a couple I met on a train that Michael Gove was a 'toad of a man', which really annoyed them.

Comment: @Michael Harvey  and KateBunting What's this: a girl of an angel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use an expression like this to say someone or something is very much like something else in a significant way:

> [a person or thing] **is a** [thing 1] **of a** [thing 2]

1. [thing 1] is what we are saying the person or thing **is like.**
2. [thing 2] is what the person or thing **really is.**

Usually [thing 1] is an unreal thing:

**John is a bull of a man.** A bull is a big strong animal which can be difficult to obstruct or divert, and can be clumsy and cause damage. John is a man who is big and strong and can be difficult to obstruct or divert physically or figuratively and may be clumsy. He is not a bull really (a bull is an animal).

**Mary is an angel of a girl.** An angel is a mythical being which is entirely good, beautiful, etc. Mary is especially good, virtuous, kind, beautiful, etc. She is not really an 'angel' (angels are mythical beings).

**My teenage son lives in a pigsty of a room.** A pigsty is a farm building where pigs are kept. It can be offensively dirty and smelly. My son's room is very dirty. It is not really a pigsty (there are no pigs in it).

**"Bliss" is a train wreck of a movie.**
A train wreck is a situation where there is a great deal of noise and chaos, and nothing good results. "Bliss" is a very bad film in which a lot of chaotic things happen, but nothing good is provided to the viewer. There are no trains wrecked in the film.

Native speakers will very often omit the last part (of a [thing 2]) like this

John is a bull.

Mary is an angel.

My son lives in a pigsty.

"Bliss" is a train wreck.

The statement is so unreal that the hearer immediately understands that a comparison is being made.

To reverse the statement, e.g. John is a man of a bull, Mary is a girl of an angel, my son lives in a room of a pigsty, will be heard as a nonsensical utterance and will be, most often, meaningless. '"Bliss" is a movie of a train wreck' would be grammatical but completely untrue.

Comment: And this is a helluva answer. [Note to learner: hell of a] :) Why don't the commenters upvote what is a perfectly good answer??

Comment: @Lambie - thank you for your kind words.

Comment: No worries, mate. This kind of answer with concrete examples that show exactly how something works is my favorite kind of answer. No mucking about.