# the structure of 'a fool of a person' and 'an angel of a woman'

Tags: phrase-usage

> an angel of a woman (a woman is like an angel)

Q. a fool of a person (a person is like a fool?)

Comment: What are you asking that is different from [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/301257/an-angel-of-a-girl-an-angel-of-a-girl-or-an-angel-of-a-girl-or-an-ang)?

Comment: 'An angel of a woman' makes an unreal or figurative comparison between an angel (angels don't exist) and a woman (she is a real woman). A fool of a person is a real person who is really a fool.

Comment: 'a fool of a person' appears here first as an independent subject matter in regard to 'structure'.